# Convert a layout to an image, how to have a good quality?

Tags: java, android, image-capture, image-compression

I have a layout in an Android activity, I convert it as an image and then share it on different social networks. 
The things is that the quality is not good at all, I have artifacts on the image, and the quality depend of the size of the screen.

Is there any way to improve the quality ? I can't store the complete layout image as a static image in the application directory, I need it to be generated on the go.

Here is code I use to transform the layout into a PNG.

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;   
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dashboardView.getWidth(),
                    dashboardView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            dashboardView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Logger.e(e.toString());
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        File path = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, "wayzupDashboard" + ".png");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit: My bad, I left ARGB_4444, the fact is I made a lot of test before posting the question on SO, I just forgot to put ARGB_8888 in. Still the image quality is bad on Android phone with tiny screen. If only I could tell to always use HDPI drawable while capturing the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARGB_4444 means that you have only 4 bits per channel (a really poor quality).

Use ARGB_8888.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I tried a lot of different configuration, I just pasted the code before write back ARGB_888. Still the quality from tiny screen is bad. Any way I can tell Android to use HDPI ressources folder while capturing it ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to change used drawable folder for a while and then back to previous used folder.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444`. I suggest you to use ARGB_8888, like Google [tells us](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)

> `ARGB_4444` This field was deprecated in API level . Because of the
>   poor quality of this configuration, it is advised to use `ARGB_8888`
>   instead.